# is vertical scaling good idea for a mysql database server?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, clustering, scalability

I operate a mariadb/mysql database server and i do not want to get into the problems with managing a multi-cluster database server
i have access to huge CPU and RAM and STORAGE when needed

so my question to the experienced and expert db admins is that is vertical scaling good enough? yes downtime is ok as long as data is protected 
I rather deal with downtime of some system failure or issue that will only happen very rarely...it is better than the headache with managing a multi-cluster database to me

so what are the bottlenecks i will run into running a database up to 512GB memory and like 128vCPU? and like 2TB of SSD storage?

how is this worse than lets say running like a 8 cluster of mariadb/mysql database with each 64GB memory, 16vCPU and 256GB SSD storage?

yes i know about iops but i mean with lots of redis caching i think one can reduce stress on that part as well

pretty much there is more and more powerful CPU and servers that one can pack lots of stuffs in a single machine..not like years ago where that was not possible or at least easy..now one can pack several Terabytes, TBs(not a typo) of memory in a single machine

please send your advice and tips
thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You can't throw hardware at a performance problem."  Or, rather, you can't do that twice.

- CPU speed has not changed significantly in 20 years.
- The number of cores increases, but InnoDB has always hit a brick wall before using all cores.
- SSDs were a quantum improvement over HDDs, but nothing is on the horizon for the next leap.
- Bigger RAM (hence buffer_pool) gets into "diminishing returns".
- Ethernet makes a 10x "speedup" every so often.
- It would take years to fill a Petabyte disk; don't you want to *read* the data before that?
- etc.

One trick is to virtualize a big hunk of iron by having multiple VMs, each running an instance of MySQL.  This does "horizontal" scaling on a single "vertically" scaled server.  This at least helps with the brick wall I mentioned.  But then you have a big, costly, single-point-of-failure.

My usual answer is "let's see if we can program smarter".

A recurring example is Data Warehousing.  DBAs come to this (and other) forums bemoaning that their 'report' (a big `SELECT` with a big `GROUP BY`) is taking too long.  I point out the beauty of a Summary table -- 10x speedup, 10x smaller disk footprint.  Poof, problem gone.  *No* hardware upgrade could have gotten 10x.

Replication provides nearly infinite scaling, nearly linear, of *reads*.

Sharding (horizontal scaling) provides nearly infinite scaling, nearly linearly, but it does not work for all applications.

The best I see in Vertical is adding enough RAM to turn an I/O-bound query into a CPU-bound query running in the buffer_pool.  I regularly see a 10x improvement for that.  *But it is a one-time improvement*.  That is, adding even more RAM won't help *any more*.

So, to your title question, I say a resounding *No*.
OK, Vertical may help, but be aware of its limits.

Comment: i get your point, but am not refering to scaling vertically infinitely..i think the vertical scale am mentioning is for many scenarios where a single db server can surfice...i mean imagine a wordpress website with like 200 million pageviews a month just mostly blog content and couple images per blog posts, not video hosting...many people will think of having clusters of servers, but do you think the vertical scale am mentioning can be enough for such scenario...also there will be caching as well too...the server spec i mentioned..you think that will handle such traffic?

Comment: @uberrebu - 200M PV/mo might be the limit of available hardware today.  That's about 160/sec.  How many queries are needed for the typical PV?  How big can a burst be?  You might need a machine that can handle 5K qps.  Yes, that should be feasible by Vertical scaling.  While you are at it, fix the inefficiency in `postmeta`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: queries will be basic queries to read the blog post..there will be nginx page caching and redis object caching...so there wont be too much stress on the database server...what spec of a single machine do you think will handle the 200 M PV/month? what are your recommended specs?

Comment: @uberrebu - Calculate the bandwidth needed.  How many bytes in a page; assume 500 pages/sec; ... Now does your Ethernet card, your modem, your IPS, etc, have that much bandwidth.  _That_ may be the gating issue.

Comment: each pageview is average 1.25MB..there will be cloudflare CDN free version for light static caching as well...i just want to know single database server can handle this..i will work on bandwidth issue if that comes up to be bottleneck

Comment: most of the page size of 1.25MB is from static images..so i can offload that to CDN...also server comes with dual 10gigabit network ports..so bandwidth will not be a problem as will be under 10 gigabits even at 500 pageviews/sec and 1.25MB per pageview

Comment: @uberrebu - 10Gb (bits) caps out at about 700MB (bytes), which is not much more than 500 * 1.25MB.  So, keep an eye on that.

Comment: so what is recommended `single` hardware to handle wordpress site with 500 pageviews/sec for mariadb database server?

Comment: @uberrebu MariaDB on a beefy machine should be as good as anything.  When you get to 50 PV/sec, gather some metrics and start a new Question.

Comment: any IOPS bottleneck to watch for? Will i need a RAID storage for better IOPS? or will a single SSD suffice?

Comment: @uberrebu - Again, I recommend taking a checkpoint at 50/sec.  By then there may be better options that you will be drooling to upgrade to, anyway.  Meanwhile, my suggested fix to postmeta will help with I/O and CPU, but not network bandwidth.

Comment: @uberrebu - Anyway, the real question is not about disk subsystem but about whether 64GB of RAM will hold most of the posts (etc).  If it will, there will be very little I/O.  If not, _then_ IOPs and RAID becomes an issue.  WP has some inefficiencies, but I don't think it uses UUIDs, which would be terrible with too-little RAM.

Comment: I mentioned i can get up to 512GB of memory potentially even getting to 1TB of memory if need be..on a single machine...so am willing to go badly vertical like a behemoth..and pack it with the most power dual xeon E5 available..just want to get the idea of clustered database server out of my mind because i tell you ppl have no idea what it takes to manage that thing..and there are more risks involved than running a single instance db server

Comment: OK 512GB or 1TB.  How much space will the "average" user need on disk?  I suggest that 90% of your clients will write a few blogs, then vanish.  I doubt if 1% will hit a GB of stuff.  My point is that once the RAM goes beyond the disk footprint of the data, it is wasted money.

Comment: yeah i rather have more RAM than needed than have the database server be struggling and getting stressed..yeah thanks for your response...will keep on my single database server theory still

Comment: @uberrebu - I'll be interested to hear how it goes, and what you find out in a few months.

Comment: @uberrebu any updates?

Comment: @platypus - Write a Question that describes your particular situation; include specific questions.